# How to remove diverged issue after pulling the changes?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I ran `git pull` and got this message,

```sh
On branch main
Your branch and 'origin/main' have diverged,
and have 2 and 3464 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
```

I want to undo the `git pull` and return back to `2` commits state. How do I do that? I tried `git reset --keep HEAD@{1}`, `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`. None of them work. I still the error message.

Comment: What do you mean by "the 2 commits state"? The output you show looks like it is from `git status`. What did `git pull` report?

Comment: `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`. I just wanna know if my original code is messed up after pull. Both original and new ones have the exact amount of files. I am not sure how I can check what `git pull` messed.

Comment: `git pull` did nothing but download the upstream history. You have your own, separate history in your repository (therefore, "unrelated"), because it looks like you took the files from upstream, but not their commits, and then made your own 2 commits. You are already "back at the 2 commits state". If that is all you needed, then there is nothing to do for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

```sh
git log --oneline

# Write down the commit hash before the issue

git reset --hard <COMMIT_HASH>
```

Comment: I get this: `HEAD is now at 30e6dc8d init` but I when I do `git status`, I still get that message `Your branch and 'origin/main' have diverged, and have 2 and 3464 different commits each, respectively.`.

Comment: Please, post your `git log --oneline`.

Comment: `30e6dc8d (HEAD -> main) init` and `c2debef2 first commit`